# cakephp2 can't get file data array through $this->request->data

Tags: ajax, cakephp, file-upload

usually, we get all the data we need from $this->request->data. but if I'm using ajax file upload, I can't get that data e.g: tmp_name, size, etc.

my javascript code is like:

```
function uploadFile(file_blob_chunk, file_name, file_part, total_file_chunk, file_id) {
fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file_for_upload", file_blob_chunk);
    fd.append("somestring", "This is some extra data");

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();             
xhr.open("POST", "files/index/" + file_id + '/' + file_part, true);

//Onload happened after file finished uploaded
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    //alert(file_name + "done");     
};

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {        
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    }}, false);

xhr.send(fd);
}
```

and in FilesController.php

```
public function index($file_id = null, $file_part = null) { 
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //I can't use $this->request->data, to get the file details
    }
}
```

If I use

```
debug($this->request->data);
```

I will only get

```
array(
    'somestring' => 'This is some extra data'
)
```

I can't get the file data

Unless Im using debug($_FILES), I won't get

```
array(
    'file_for_upload' => array(
        'name' => 'blob',
        'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'tmp_name' => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpAC42.tmp',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'size' => (int) 9304862
    )
)
```

Comment: Go to the source?  [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)  Assuming that "framework" doesn't strip them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `$this->request->data` your post data should be in the format cake expects, eg: `data[Model][some_field]`

you have `CustomField`

Comment: I think u misunderstand it, "CustomField" is just string... I will edit my post pls check it

Comment: `data[Model][some_field]` is also just a string. The only difference is `data[Model][some_field]` is cake format and `customField` is not.

Comment: no, I meant if I use $this->request->data then I can get the customfield one (which I change the text to "somestring").. I will not get "file_for_upload" one